# How to load and compile Java code from a jar file into a java project?

Tags: java, jar, urlclassloader

I'm trying to load a .jar file into my project dinamically: my programme has to look in a directory in my pc and load the code inside all the jar files as it was part of the project since the beginning.

I need to be able to call method from that class, and also if in my project I have the class `Bee` and in the jar file I have the class `QueenBee extends Bee` it has to work without the class `Bee` in the jar file.

I tried using URLClassLoader:

```
String homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
String modsPath = homeDir + File.separator + "AppData" + File.separator + "Roaming" + File.separator + ".minecraft" + File.separator + "mods";
File modsFolder = new File(modsPath);
if(modsFolder.exists() && modsFolder.isDirectory()){
    for (File file : Objects.requireNonNull(modsFolder.listFiles())){
        if(!getFileExtension(file).equals("jar")){
            continue;
        }
        // Load the class from the JAR file.
        URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()});
        Class<?> modClass;
        try{
            modClass = classLoader.loadClass("mymod.MyMod");
            modClass.getDeclaredMethod("scanMods").invoke(modClass);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

The jar file is:

```
file.jar
|_ _ mymod (folder)
      |_ _ MyMod.java
```

But I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mymod.MyMod`

I probably need something different than URLClassLoader?

Comment: Have a look at https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html

Comment: Actually, I discovered that the problem is I can't load .java files but just .class compiled files. However, I'd like to know if there's a method to load not .java files and compile them programmatically.